# Select the exact one cell from table and change state of this

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have got table dynamically created in react

```
    const [greenPlace, setGreenPlace] = useState({green: false})
    const placesInRow = parseInt(props.places / props.rows)

    const changeColor = (e) => {
            const id = e.target.value
            setGreenPlace({green: true})
    }
```

---

```
 <div className={'obj-table'}>
    <table>
        <tbody>
          {
              [...Array(props.rows)].map((row, rowIdx) =>
                  <tr key={rowIdx}>
                    {
                        [...Array(placesInRow)].map((x, idx) =>
                            <td key={rowIdx + 1 > 1 ? (idx + 1) + (rowIdx * 10) : idx + 1}
                                className={`${greenPlace.green ? 'greenTd' : 'whiteTd'} font-link`}
                                onClick={changeColor}
                              >{rowIdx + 1 > 1 ? (idx + 1) + (rowIdx * 10) : idx + 1}
                            </td>
                        )
                    }
                 </tr>
              )
          }
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

which looks like that on website

[image]

What I want to achieve is to change the color to green for only one cell after click on this cell. The code I have got change the color but for every cell, not the exact one I clicked.
I tried to work with `id's` but I am not sure how it should looks like.

I tried something like this:

```
const [choosenPlaces, setChoosenPlaces] = useState([])
```

---

```
 const changeColor = (e) => {
            const id = e.target.id
            setGreenPlace({green: true})
            setChoosenPlaces(prevArray => [...prevArray, id])
            console.log(choosenPlaces)
    }
```

but when I try to `console.log` those `choosenPlaces` to check if it works, the website reloads with errors.

Comment: Have you tried to use the state variable to store which cell has been clicked?

Comment: I created this `useState` `const [choosenPlaces, setChoosenPlaces] = useState([])` then in my `changeColor` method put it like this `setChoosenPlaces(prevArray => [...prevArray, id])` but when I try to `console.log(choosenPlaces)` the website reloads with errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are doing is that you are updating `greenPlace` state to be true for all the cell.

So instead of that, you should store which cell is being clicked by storing `rowIdx` and `idx` in your state like below:-

```
  const [greenPlace, setGreenPlace] = useState({});
  
  const changeColor = (rowIdx, idx) => {
    setGreenPlace({ rowIdx, idx });
  };
```

Now your logic to check `className` and your `onClick` function will be like below:-

```
<td
  key={rowIdx + 1 > 1 ? idx + 1 + rowIdx * 10 : idx + 1}
  className={`${
    greenPlace.rowIdx === rowIdx && greenPlace.idx === idx
      ? 'greenTd'
      : 'whiteTd'
    } font-link`}
  onClick={() => changeColor(rowIdx, idx)}
>
  {rowIdx + 1 > 1 ? idx + 1 + rowIdx * 10 : idx + 1}
</td>
```

Comment: it works, but what if I would like to save the state for clicked cells? I mean, let's say I clicked cell with number x and it is green now, but when I click the other cell with number y, the cell with number x change to white. How can I save this green color to cell with number x?

Comment: For that you need to convert state into array and then store value in that state. Here is demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-7ubjwf?file=src%2FApp.js

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution:

```
import React,{useState} from "react";
import "./style.css";
import './color.css';
export default function App() {
  let cellList,className,rowList=[];
  const [greenPlace, setGreenPlace] = useState(0);
  let updateLocation=(value)=>{
    setGreenPlace(value);
  }
  for (let y=0;y<10;y++){
    cellList=[];
    for (let x=1;x<=10;x++){
      let value=(x+y*10);
      className=((value===greenPlace)?"green":"");
      cellList.push(
        <td 
          className={className}          
          onClick={()=>updateLocation(value)}>
          {value}
        </td>
      )
    }
    rowList.push(<tr>{cellList}</tr>)
  }
  return (
    <table border="1">
      {rowList}
    </table>
  );
}
```

The demo site is [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-cf1qwz).